# What are the prefered names for true and false in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, boolean

In Clojure, if I'm writing a test function and want to return boolean values from it, what's the right way to express these?

Comment: Be careful! The Clojure *fact* is that everything but `false` and `nil` act as true. The Clojure *idiom* is to take advantage of this. So your should not generally test for equality with Boolean values. For instance `(= false (and nil false))` is `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`true` and `false` are perfectly valid in Clojure

```
Give me some Clojure:
> true
true
> false
false
> (type true)
java.lang.Boolean
> (type false)
java.lang.Boolean
```

Comment: Ah ... so they are. The somehow I couldn't find that in the documentation.

Comment: For a more official source, see the Literals section of http://clojure.org/reader